# Проблема с волокнами, приложение падает

Tags: c, многопоточность, winapi

VS 2015, консольное x64 приложение.

Начал изучать для себя облегченные потоки (волокна\fibers). Информации и примеров по данному направлению очень мало. Нашел этот пример на одном из форумов:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#define N 30 // Fibers counter

typedef struct
{
    int counter, fiberID;
    LPVOID nextFiber;
} *PFiberData;

VOID WINAPI Executable(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    PFiberData pfd = (PFiberData)lpParam;
    pfd->counter++;
    printf("Fiber #%i, counter value was %i, new value is %i\n", pfd->fiberID + 1, pfd->counter - 1, pfd->counter);
    SwitchToFiber(pfd->nextFiber);
}

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    PFiberData data[N];
    LPVOID pFibers[N + 1];
    printf("Launched %u fibers\r\n", N);
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        data[i] = (PFiberData)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, sizeof(int));
        data[i]->counter = rand() % 1000;
        data[i]->fiberID = i;
        pFibers[i] = CreateFiber(0, Executable, data[i]);
        if (!pFibers[i])
            printf("Cannot create fiber\r\n");
        if (i>0)
            data[i - 1]->nextFiber = pFibers[i];
    }
    pFibers[N] = ConvertThreadToFiber(0);
    data[N - 1]->nextFiber = pFibers[N];
    SwitchToFiber(pFibers[0]);

    // Close all fibers and free memory allocations.
    for (int i = 0; i<N; i++)
        DeleteFiber(pFibers[i]);
    printf("Done\r\n");

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

При указании константы N = 3 приложение нормально отрабатывает. Но если увеличить число фиберов - приложение падает. В чем причина падения приложения?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Под отладчиком запускать пробовали? При каком N начинает падать? С какой ошибкой падает?

Comment: @alexolut, падает при N равным 30 и больше. Пробовал и под отладчиком, но ничего отладка не прояснила. Ошибка: Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x00007FFDC91A7400 (kernel32.dll) в FiberTest.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

Comment: на какой строке падает? Что успевает вывести в консоль? Добавьте всё это в сам вопрос путем его редактирования.

Comment: @alexolut, добавил.

Comment: Попробуйте заменить в HeapAlloc 'sizeof(int)' на 'sizeof(PFiberData)'

Comment: @alexolut, не помогло.

Comment: а если на 'sizeof(*PFiberData)'?

Comment: @alexolut, синтаксическая ошибка: "использование имени типа не допускается."

Comment: 'sizeof(*data[i])'?

Comment: А почему `SwitchToFiber(pFibers[0]);` ?

Comment: @МстиславПавлов, это у автора кода нужно спросить. alexolut - вроде бы помогло. Например при N = 64 000 все проходит нормально, а при N = 300 000 приложение падает. Я не знаю, есть ли лимит у волокон на один процесс как у потоков, может быть дело в лимите.

Comment: Да, дело в лимите, при перешагивании порога 65 000 (как и у потоков) - падение.

Comment: @alexolut, не помогло, падает через раз уже с другой ошибкой: "Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x00007FF7420F0F88 в FiberTest.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (параметры: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000A198953000)."